# Apple push notification one app more subdomains

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can i set apple push notification when i connect to `sub1.domain.com` my server will send messages for that `APP_ID`, and when connect to `sub2.domain.com` i will receive messages only from that subdomain.

Like in GCM, i have 5 apps for 5 subdomains and my ios app connect to another app_id and get token for that app(subdomain).

Is that possible in apple push notifications?

Comment: All subdomains backed the same one database?

Comment: Not one database, but one app will be used for multi subdomains, so i don't need to make 5 apps on app store for 5 customers, i have 1 app that connects to 5 subdomains and receive messages for only that subdomain..

Comment: In your database or databases where you register your remote notification token you need to record which subdomain the user is associated with. You can then target your push notifications appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS remote push notification just requests a device token, and APNs just send message to device via device token. The device token is unique to iDevice.

For your purpose, you can save both device token and a "token channel" to database, e.g. `INSERT INTO device_tokens (channel, token) VALUES ('subdomain1', 'xxxxxxxxx')`, when sending message, queue device token with channel, e.g. `SELECT token FROM device_tokens WHERE channel = 'subdomain1'`